# Do I have to use cfqueryparam for static values?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Do I have to use cfqueryparam for static values?

Say I have this as my where clause:

```
WHERE status = 1
```

Is there any benefit when doing it like:

```
WHERE id = <cfqueryparam value="1" maxlength="32" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
```

I use that 1 value repeatedly throughout my queries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using cfqueryparam with constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141672/using-cfqueryparam-with-constants)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to. There is no security gain from param'ing static text.

However there is a performance gain in query optimization so it is still a gain to do so but this only applies when a new query must be run, so its not a gain beyond the first run of a static query.

Always param variables though.

Comment: There is not always a performance gain - only if your DBMS can use bind variables.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 8.4